# Linear Function: y = mx + b (2 points given) in code

Tags: c#, math, linear-algebra

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong, as this should be fairly simple...
I have 2 given points plus X from the third - and now I need Y from that third line.

That's a really simple equation: y = mx + b.
But because I can't use this in my C#-program (well, I'm sure there's a library for that, but performance matters here), I'm trying to "write the formula out".

My function looks like this:

```
public static float GetY(Vector2 point1, Vector2 point2, float x)
    {
        var m = (point2.Y - point1.Y) / (point2.X + point1.Y);
        var b = point1.Y - (m * point1.X);

        return m*x + b;
    }
```

Now something in this formula is wrong, because sometimes I don't get the right value. Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "because sometimes I don't get the right value" - and that means?

Comment: Can you give an example of inputs that give the wrong output, together with the expected output?

Comment: It is a simple bug in your `m` calculation, use point1.X instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your posted code, you seem to have made a typo. This:

```
var m = (point2.Y - point1.Y) / (point2.X + point1.Y);
```

...should be:

```
var m = (point2.Y - point1.Y) / (point2.X - point1.X);
```

Comment: @Rawling: Haha, yes, I forgot to fix that bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You want this:

```
public static float GetY(Vector2 point1, Vector2 point2, float x)
    {
        var dx = point2.X - point1.x;  //This part has problem in your code
        if (dx == 0)
            return float.NaN;
        var m = (point2.Y - point1.Y) / dx;
        var b = point1.Y - (m * point1.X);

        return m*x + b;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I would have thought that:

```
var m = (point2.Y - point1.Y) / (point2.X + point1.Y);
```

should be

```
var m = (point2.Y - point1.Y) / (point2.X - point1.X);
```

Gradient is the delta in Y divided by the delta in X.

Answer (score 1):

You've put point1.y twice in the formula for m. 
Additionally as noticed by Jacob it should be a minus!

Think you want

```
var m = (point2.Y - point1.Y) / (point2.X - point1.X);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you do not try to write a separate function that calculate m so it just be passed as a parameter to this new function that is like predicting the y of the passed x . M should be constant and also b for all x being passed and y being calculated . Is not it?